# React onChange method not working in login form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

I'm facing this problem while trying to move input value to component state hook using the onChange attribute.
i'll be happy with your help.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import './userInterface.css';

function UserInterface() {

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    isLoggedIn : '',
    userName : '',
    email : '',
    password : ''
  })


  let usenamePattern = /[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}./ ;
  let emailPattern = /[A-Za-z0-9@.]{7,}/ ;
  
  
  const getInputToState = (e,inputField) => {
    
    
    
    switch(inputField){
      case 'username' : {
        setUserInfo(userInfo.userName = e.target.value) 
        console.log(userInfo)
        break
      }
      case 'email' : {
        setUserInfo(userInfo.email = e.target.value)
        console.log(userInfo)
        break
      }
      case 'password' : {
        setUserInfo(userInfo.password = e.target.value) 
        console.log(userInfo)
        break
      }
      default:
        return null
  
      }
      console.log(userInfo)

    
    
  }


  
  
  const alertForm = () => {


    if(userInfo.userName == '' && userInfo.email == '' && userInfo.password == ''){
      return{
        msg : '',
        color : 'green'
      }
    }
    
    else if(userInfo.userName.match(usenamePattern)){
      return {
        msg : 'You are allright !',
        color : 'limegreen'
      }
    }else if(!userInfo.userName.match(usenamePattern)){
      return {
        msg : 'Username should be more than 3 characters and less than 16, and contains only alphabets and numbers',
        color : 'red'
      }
    }

    
    
  }



  

  return (
    <div id='user-div'>
        <form id='user-form'>

            <h2 id="form-title">Tell us who you are :)</h2>

            <ul id="form-inputs">
              <li className="form-input">
                <input type="text" className="user-input" placeholder='Enter a username' maxLength={16} onChange={getInputToState()}/>          
              </li>
              <li className="form-input">
                <input type="text" className="user-input" placeholder='Enter your e-mail' onChange={getInputToState()}/>
              </li>
              <li className="form-input">
                <input type="text" className="user-input" placeholder='Create a password' onChange={(e) => {getInputToState()}}/>
              </li>
              <li className="form-input">
                <a><button className='action-form' id='submit-button' disabled>Submit</button></a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <h4 id='alert-msg' style={{color : alertForm()?.color}}>{alertForm()?.msg}</h4>


            

            <h3 id='login-sign'>Already have an account ? <a href="/" id='login-form'>Log In</a></h3>
            
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UserInterface ;
```

here is the entire component code, it has no relation with props or exports.
When i write in inputs the console returns nothing which means that the function do not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first you should do is change

`onChange={(e) => {getInputToState()}}`

to

`onChange={(e) => {() => getInputToState( e, 'your_field_name' )}}`

And inside your `getInputToState` function you should pass to `setUserInfo` new `userInfo` object with mutated fields or one field. Hope this will help.

Your function should look like this:

```
const getInputToState = (e, inputField) =>
{
  const newUserInfo = userInfo; // create new state object

  userInfo[inputField] = e.target.value; // Change th value

  setUserInfo(newUserInfo); // Set new state

};
```

You also can get rid of the switch statement.

Comment: can you explain how to pass new userInfo to setUserInfo

Comment: I've edited the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this would be to use:

```
onChange={(e) => getInputToState(e, "username")}
onChange={(e) => getInputToState(e, "email")}
onChange={(e) => getInputToState(e, "password")}
```

The switch statement will not default to null and give the desired results.

---

*Also see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73525622/how-to-give-the-string-value-to-the-parameter-in-onchange-in-react/).*

Comment: it actually works but only for one character if i enter a second one it gives me #Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'userName' on string.

Comment: This is because of how you are handling the setState function in getInputToState(). Try this instead:

`setUserInfo((prevUserInfo) => ({ ...prevUserInfo, userName: val }));`